# Undefined offset: 0 in /tmp/umsp-plugins/pakfiles/pakfiles.php on line 167

Tags: php

Trying to run this code but getting error for Undefined offset: 0 on line 167 in following code. I am not understaing what does it mean as i am a new starter to php and was trying to understand this code.

```
<?php
# pakfiles ver.0.1 - UMSP-plugin for http://www.pakfiles.com
# Info - http://forum.wdlxtv.com/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=9235
 include 'myhoster.php';
//include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/umsp/plugins/hosters/hosters.php';


function _pluginMain($prmQuery) {
$prmQuery = htmlspecialchars_decode($prmQuery);
if (strpos($prmQuery,'&amp;')!==false) $prmQuery=str_replace('&amp;','&',$prmQuery);
 parse_str($prmQuery, $queryData);
      $items = array();

      if(isset($queryData['cat']) && $queryData['cat']!="")
        showMoviesMenu($items, $prmQuery);
     else if(isset($queryData['episode']) && isset($queryData['load']))
    showStreamsMenu($items, $prmQuery);
     else if(isset($queryData['tvshow']) && $queryData['tvshow']!="")
    showALLEpisodesMenu($items, $prmQuery);
     else if(isset($queryData['episode']) && $queryData['episode']!="")
    showEpisodesMenu($items, $prmQuery);
     else {
                 if (file_exists ('/var/log/apache2/proxylo.txt')) unlink('/var/log/apache2/proxylo.txt');
         $cats = array(
                        'PakDramas:Dramas',
                        'videos:Videos',
                        'talkShows:Talk Shows',
         );
         foreach($cats as $cat) {
            $cat = explode(":", $cat);
            $items[] = array(
               'id'              => "umsp://plugins/pakfiles?cat=".urlencode($cat[0]),
               'dc:title'        => $cat[1],
               'upnp:class'      => 'object.container',
               'upnp:album_art'  => ''
            );
         }

      }

      return $items;
    }

    function showMoviesMenu(&$items, $prmQuery) {
    $prmQuery = htmlspecialchars_decode($prmQuery);
    if (strpos($prmQuery,'&amp;')!==false) $prmQuery=str_replace('&amp;','&',$prmQuery);
    parse_str($prmQuery, $queryData);

                $cat = $queryData['cat'];
                $cat = str_replace("&amp;","&",$cat);

                if (($cat === 'PakDramas') || ($cat === 'videos') || ($cat === 'talkShows')) {
                        $url = 'http://www.pakfiles.com/';
                        if ($cat === 'PakDramas')  {

                                $url = 'http://www.pakfiles.com/pakistani-dramas';

                                $html = @file_get_contents($url);

                                $html = str_replace("\r","",$html);
                                $html = str_replace("\n"," ",$html);
                                $html = str_replace("\t","",$html);
                                $pattern = '|<div class="list-group">(.*?)</div>|';
                                preg_match($pattern, $html, $data);
                                $pattern = '|<a href="([^"]+)" title="[^"]+"\s* class="([^"]+)">([^<]+)</a>|';
                                preg_match_all($pattern, $data[1], $subcats, PREG_SET_ORDER);
//print_r($subcats);
                                foreach ($subcats as $subcat){

                                        $items[] = array(
                                                'id'              => 'umsp://plugins/pakfiles?tvshow='.urlencode($subcat[1])."&amp;title=".urlencode($subcat[3]),
                                                'dc:title'        => $subcat[3],
                                                'upnp:album_art'  => '',
                                                'upnp:class'      => 'object.container',
                                        );
                                }
                                return $items;
                        }

                        else if (($cat === 'videos') || ($cat === 'talkShows')){
                 if ($cat == 'videos')
                  $url ='http://www.pakfiles.com/browse-videos';
        if ($cat == 'talkShows')  
            $url ='http://www.pakfiles.com/browse-talkshows';
                                $html = @file_get_contents($url);
                              //$html = @file_get_contents($url);

                                $html = str_replace("\r","",$html);
                                $html = str_replace("\n"," ",$html);
                                $html = str_replace("\t","",$html);
                                $pattern = '|<div class="list-group">(.*?)</div>|';
                               // $pattern = '|<ul id="menu-side-menu-1" class="primary-menu">(.*?)</ul>|';
                                preg_match($pattern, $html, $data);//print_r($html);
$data= preg_replace('/<i\s+[^>]*class\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"[^>]*>/', '', $data[1]);       
$data= preg_replace('/<\/i>/', '', $data);      
$data= preg_replace('/<a\s+[^>]*href\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"[^>]*>/', '<a href="\1">', $data);  
//print_r($data);
                             $pattern = '|<a href="([^"]+)">([^<]+)</a>|';
                             preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $subcats, PREG_SET_ORDER);

                             foreach ($subcats as $subcat){
//print_r($subcat);
                                        $items[] = array(
                                                'id'              => 'umsp://plugins/pakfiles?tvshow='.urlencode($subcat[1])."&amp;title=".urlencode($subcat[2]),
                                                'dc:title'        => $subcat[2],
                                                'upnp:album_art'  => '',
                                                'upnp:class'      => 'object.container',
                                        );
                                }
                                return $items;
                        }

                }

}

    function showALLEpisodesMenu(&$items, $prmQuery) {
    //print('load shows list');
    $prmQuery = htmlspecialchars_decode($prmQuery);
    if (strpos($prmQuery,'&amp;')!==false) $prmQuery=str_replace('&amp;','&',$prmQuery);
    parse_str($prmQuery, $queryData);
          $tvshow = $queryData['tvshow'];
          $title = $queryData['title'];

      ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2');
        $url = $tvshow;
        $html = @file_get_contents($url);

        $html = str_replace("\r","",$html);
        $html = str_replace("\n"," ",$html);
        $html = str_replace("\t","",$html);
        $html = str_replace("&#8211;","-",$html);
        $html = preg_replace('|\xE2\x80\x93|','-',$html);

$html= preg_replace('/<img\s+[^>]*src\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"[^>]*>/', '', $html);        
$pattern = '|<div class="thumbnail">(.*?)</div>|';
        preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $episodes);
//print_r($episodes);   
$episodes=$episodes[1];
//print_r($episodes);

$episodes= preg_replace('/<a\s+[^>]*href\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"[^>]*>/', '<a href="\1">', $episodes);  
$episodes= preg_replace('/<b class="thumb_title">/', '<span class="thumb_title">', $episodes);  
$episodes= preg_replace('/<\/b>/', '</span>', $episodes);  
//print_r($episodes);
foreach($episodes as $episode) {
//      $pattern = '|<a title="([^"]+)" href="([^"]+)">|';
        $pattern = '|<a href="([^"]+)">|';
                                   preg_match_all($pattern, $episode, $epis, PREG_SET_ORDER);
//print_r($epis);
        //$pattern = '|<span class="([^"]+)">([^<]+)</span>|';
        $pattern = '|<h3 class="thumb_title">([^<]+)</h3>|';        


preg_match_all($pattern, $episode, $span, PREG_SET_ORDER);                           
//print_r($span);
if(empty($span))
{ 
$pattern = '|<span class="thumb_title">([^<]+)</span>|';  
preg_match_all($pattern, $episode, $span, PREG_SET_ORDER); 
}
preg_match_all($pattern, $episode, $span, PREG_SET_ORDER);
//$pattern = '|<a target="_blank" href="([^"]+)" title="([^"]+)" href="([^"]+)">|';
                $title=$span[0][1];   
                $items[] = array(
                   'id'              => "umsp://plugins/pakfiles?episode=".urlencode($epis[0][1])."&amp;title=".urlencode($title),
                   'dc:title'        => $title,
                   'upnp:class'      => 'object.container',
                );     
}

$pattern = '|<a href="([^"]+)" >([^"]+)</a>|';
preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $pages, PREG_SET_ORDER);
//print_r($pages);
foreach($pages as $page)
{
if($page[1]=='#')
{
$pno=$page[2]+1;
}}
$url=$queryData['tvshow'];
if(isset($queryData['cpage'])!=""){
$nexturl=substr($url,0,strlen($url)-strlen($cpage)-2);
//print_r($nexturl);
}
else
{
if(substr($url,-2)=='-1')
{
$url=substr($url,0,strlen($url)-2);
}
$nexturl=$url;
}
                $items[] = array(
                   'id'              => 'umsp://plugins/pakfiles?tvshow='.urlencode($nexturl) . "-".$pno."&amp;cpage=".$pno." &amp;title=" .$queryData['title'],
                   'dc:title'        => 'Next',
                   //'upnp:album_art'  => '',
                   'upnp:class'      => 'object.container',
                );
foreach($pages as $page)
{
if($page[1]=='#')
{
//print_r($page[2]+1);
$pno=$page[2]-1;
//print_r($pno);
}}
if($pno>0)
{
if(isset($queryData['cpage'])){
$prevurl=substr($url,0,strlen($url)-strlen($cpage)-2);
//print_r($url);
}
                $items[] = array(
                   'id'              => 'umsp://plugins/pakfiles?tvshow='.urlencode($prevurl) . "-".$pno."&amp;cpage=".$pno." &amp;title=" .$queryData['title'],
                   'dc:title'        => 'Prev',
                   //'upnp:album_art'  => '',
                   'upnp:class'      => 'object.container',
                );
}

return $items;
}

function showEpisodesMenu(&$items, $prmQuery) {
$prmQuery = htmlspecialchars_decode($prmQuery);
if (strpos($prmQuery,'&amp;')!==false) $prmQuery=str_replace('&amp;','&',$prmQuery);
 parse_str($prmQuery, $queryData);
          $episode = $queryData['episode'];
          $title = $queryData['title'];

      ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2');

        if (strpos($episode,'http://') === false)
                $url = 'http://www.pakfiles.com'.$episode;
        else
                $url = $episode;

        $html = @file_get_contents($url);
        $html = str_replace("\r","",$html);
        $html = str_replace("\n"," ",$html);
        $html =str_replace("\t","",$html);
$html= preg_replace('/<img\s+[^>]*src\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"[^>]*>/', '', $html);  

//<a target="_blank" class="t_share" data-url="http://www.pakfiles.com/watch-susral-meri-behen-ka-episode-6-166888" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http://www.pakfiles.com/watch-susral-meri-behen-ka-episode-6-166888"  data-lang="en">
$pattern = '|<a target="_blank" class="t_share" data-url="([^"]+)"|';
        preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $latest);
//print_r($latestURL[1][0]);
$items[] = array(
                           'id'              => "umsp://plugins/pakfiles?episode=".urlencode($latest[1][0])."&amp;title=latest&amp;load=1",
                           'dc:title'        => $title. " (***New***)",
                           'upnp:class'      => 'object.container');
$pattern = '|<div class="thumbnail">(.*?)</div>|';
        preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $episodes);
$episodes=$episodes[1];
unset($episodes[0]);  
//print_r($episodes); 
foreach($episodes as $episode) {
//$pattern = '|<a target="([^"]+)" href="([^"]+)" title="([^"]+)" href="([^"]+)">|';
$pattern = '|<a href="([^"]+)" title="([^"]+)" target="_blank">|';
                          preg_match_all($pattern, $episode, $epis, PREG_SET_ORDER);
                          //print_r($epis); 
           // $title=ucwords(substr($epis[0][3],0,strpos($epis[0][3],'uploaded')-1));   
            $title=ucwords($epis[0][2]);   
             $items[] = array(
                           'id'              => "umsp://plugins/pakfiles?episode=".urlencode($epis[0][1])."&amp;title=".urlencode($title) ."&amp;load=1",
                           'dc:title'        => $title,
                           'upnp:class'      => 'object.container',
                        );

                }

        return $items;
}

    function showStreamsMenu(&$items, $prmQuery) {
$prmQuery = htmlspecialchars_decode($prmQuery);
if (strpos($prmQuery,'&amp;')!==false) $prmQuery=str_replace('&amp;','&',$prmQuery);
 parse_str($prmQuery, $queryData);
          $episode = $queryData['episode'];
          $title = $queryData['title'];

      ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2');

        if (strpos($episode,'http://') === false)
                $url = 'http://www.pakfiles.com'.$episode;
        else
                $url = $episode;

        $html = @file_get_contents($url);
        $html = str_replace("\r","",$html);
        $html = str_replace("\n"," ",$html);
        $html =str_replace("\t","",$html);
//print_r($url);
/*$pattern = '|<meta name="twitter:video:source" content="([^"]+)"|';
preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $url);
print_r($url);
$url=explode(':',$url[1][0]);
$url='http:'.$url[2];
$buttontext="Video Not Found";
    if(strcmp($url,"mp4"))
    {
    $buttontext=(($url !== '')? 'Play'  : "Video Not Found");
    }

    else
    {
    //print_r($html);
    $temp = explode("<iframe id", $html);
    $temp=$temp[1];
    if (empty($temp)){
        //print_r("Dailymotion");
        //<iframe frameborder="0" width="100%" height="400" related="0" info="0" logo="0" src="//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x35kjdz" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        $pattern = '#<iframe frameborder="[^"]*" width="[^"]*" height="[^"]*" related="[^"]*" info="[^"]*" logo="[^"]*" src="([^"]*)" [^>]*></iframe>#';
        preg_match($pattern, $html, $tempArray);
        if(isset($tempArray[1]))
        {
            $embedUrl= "http:".$tempArray[1];
            //print_r($embedUrl);
        $videoID = getDailyMotionVideoID($embedUrl);
        $url = getDailyMotionMP4($videoID);
        if(strcmp($url,"http"))
            $buttontext="Play";
        $url=$proxy='http://127.0.0.1/umsp/plugins/pakfiles/pakfiles_proxy.php?r='. $url;
        }
    }
    }
    else
    */
    {
        //<source src="http://vmedia.gemsiptv.com/drama/nov_2015/635829254910520000.mp4" type='video/mp4' />



        //print_r("You Tube");
        //print_r($html);

        //<source src="//api.smartrix.com/home/get?v=UnTBFVnNQYk" type='video/mp4' />
        $pattern = '#<source src="([^"]*)" [^>]*>#';
        preg_match($pattern, $html, $tempArray);
        if(isset($tempArray[1]))
            {
                if(strcmp($tempArray[1],"mp4")) 
                    {
                    $url=$tempArray[1];  
                    }
                else
                    {
                    $temp="http:".$tempArray[1];
                    $temp = explode("=", $temp);
                    $videoID=$temp[1];
                    }
            }
        else
            {
            $html= preg_replace('/<iframe\s+[^>]*src\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"[^>]*>/', '<iframe src="\1">', $html); 
            $pattern = '#<iframe src="([^"]*)">#';
            preg_match($pattern, $html, $tempArray);
            if(isset($tempArray[1]))
                {
                $videoID=getYouTubeVideoID($tempArray[1]);  
                }
            }

        if (yt_exists($videoID)) 
        {
        $url = getYouTubeMovie($videoID);
        $buttontext="Play";
        } 
        else if(strcmp($url,"mp4")) 
        {
        $buttontext="Play";
        }
        else 
        { 
         $buttontext="Video Not Found";
         $url="Not Found";
         //print_r("inside");
        }

    }

                        $items[] = array(
                           'id'              => 'Pakfiles',
                           'dc:title'        => $buttontext,
                           'upnp:class'      => 'object.item.videoItem',
                           'res'             => $url,
                           'protocolInfo'    => 'http-get:*:*:*',
                        );      
}

function getDailyMotionMP4($videoID)
{

//print_r("videoid:::".$videoID);
//$videoID="184449123";
//$html = file_get_contents('http://www.dailymotion.com/json/video/' . $videoID . '?fields=stream_h264_hd_url,stream_h264_hq_url,stream_h264_url,stream_h264_sd_url');
//print_r($html);
/*preg_match_all('|"stream_h264_hd_url":"([^"]+)"|', $html, $HDURL);        //not supported
preg_match_all('|"stream_h264_hq_url":"([^"]+)"|', $html, $HDURL);          
*/
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/'.$videoID);

$tempArray = explode( 'dmp.create(document.getElementById(\'player\'), ', $html );
//print_r($tempArray[1]);
$tempArray = explode( '{}}});', $tempArray[1]);
// dispatch event for embed used on dailymotion.com
$jsonurl=$tempArray[0]."{}}}";
if(preg_match('/Content rejected/',$html))
{
    print_r("hi");
    return "";
}

$json = json_decode($jsonurl, true);
//var_dump($json);
$video = $json['metadata']['qualities'];
//print_r($video);
if (array_key_exists('380', $video)) {
  //    print_r($video['380']['0']['url']);
    $videoUrl=$video['380']['0']['url'];
}
else if (array_key_exists('480', $video)) {
   //   print_r($video['480']['0']['url']);
    $videoUrl=$video['480']['0']['url'];
}
else if (array_key_exists('380', $video)) {
  //    print_r($video['380']['0']['url']);
    $videoUrl=$video['380']['0']['url'];
}
else if (array_key_exists('240', $video)) {
    //print_r($video['240']['0']['url']);
    $videoUrl=$video['240']['0']['url'];
}

 if($videoUrl != '')
   {
  $headers = get_headers($videoUrl, 1);
  //print_r($headers);
  $videoUrl = $headers['Location'];
   }    
//print_r($videoUrl); 
   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
return $videoUrl;
}

function getDailyMotionVideoID($url)
{
//http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x2r1r6f?autoPlay=1&syndication=262479
 $pattern = '#http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/[^/]*/([^\?]*)?[^"]*#';

 preg_match($pattern, $url, $tempArray);

//print_r($tempArray);

 $videoID = $tempArray[1];

 return $videoID;
}


function yt_exists($videoID) {
    $theURL = "http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$videoID&format=json";
    $headers = get_headers($theURL);

    if (substr($headers[0], 9, 3) !== "404") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function getYouTubeVideoID($url)
{   
 $pattern = '#^.*((youtu.be/)|(v/)|(/u/\w/)|(embed/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^\#\&\?]*).*#';

 preg_match($pattern, $url, $tempArray);

 //print_r($tempArray);
 $videoID = '';

 if(isset($tempArray[7]))
 {
$videoID = $tempArray[7];
 }
 //print_r($videoID);
 return $videoID;
}

function getYouTubeMovie($videoID)
{
 $returnValue = '';

 $url = 'http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=';
 $key = 'url_encoded_fmt_stream_map';
 $content = file_get_contents($url . $videoID);

 parse_str($content,$videoParams);
 //print_r($videoParams); 
 if(isset($videoParams['reason']))
 {
return 'Error: ' . $videoParams['reason'];
 }

 $videoURLs = explode(',', $videoParams[$key]);
 foreach($videoURLs as $vURL)
 {
$sURL = $vURL;

parse_str($sURL, $urlParams);
$type = $urlParams['type'];

$tempArray = explode(';', $type);
$tempArray2 = explode('/', $tempArray[0]);
$videoFormat = $tempArray2[1];
$quality = $urlParams['quality'];

$sURL = $urlParams['url'];
if(isset($urlParams['sig']))
{
$sURL .= '&signature=' . $urlParams['sig'];
}

//      echo($sURL . "\n\n");
//print_r($videoFormat);
//print_r($sURL);
if($videoFormat == 'mp4')
{
//return the first mp4 - hopefully, the best quality
$returnValue = $sURL;
break;
}
$returnValue[] = array( 'url' => $sURL,
                 'videoFormat' => $videoFormat,
                 'quality' => $quality
              );
 }
 //echo $html;
 return $returnValue;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Undefined offset means that you try to access an array entry on line 167 with index 0 that doesn't exist. For example, when you have an array $array = [1,2,3] and you try to $array[4] then this will raise on error because the fourth index doesn't exist in the array.

Comment: "Somewhere" = the file and line in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You should reduce your question to the minimum reproducible code. It looks like your error is thrown at this line:

```
'id'=> "umsp://plugins/pakfiles?episode=".urlencode($epis[0][1])."&amp;title=".urlencode($title),
```

Check that `$epis` contains something at index 0. Generally, you can display detailed information about an array using [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) function:

```
print_r($epis);
```